# extract block number from address located in Bahrain

Tags: android, google-maps

I wanna get the block number of an address located in Bahrain.

first of all, let me show you what is block numbers.
Bahrain is divided into areas and each area has its block number like in the photo.

[image]

so, I hope the block number becomes clear to you now.

I've implemented a basic app to get the location and some of its info like this

[image]

this address is located in `BLOCK 326` but I don't have any idea about how getting the correct block num.

this feature is already built-in `Uber` and `trycarriage` apps.

I'm using Google's API to get my data.

so, any good ideas about how could that be done?

Comment: please instead of downvote write down what is wrong.

Comment: You don't indicate what geographic data source you are using. And if you are using Google's API you are showing the customer level map view (perhaps Google Maps screenshot) and not what would come out of an API.

Comment: it is google map, I just built that sample in my android studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Reverse geocoding request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?hl=en&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_375946495586-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20~%20Places%20%7C%20BMM%20%7C%20Google%20Maps%20Geocoding%20API-KWID_43700046387144782-kwd-313687192697-userloc_9061016&utm_term=KW_%2Bgoogle%20%2Bmaps%20%2Bgeocoding-ST_%2Bgoogle%20%2Bmaps%20%2Bgeocoding&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsJnalt-55gIVyoSyCh1k9QvHEAAYASAAEgIBwvD_BwE#reverse) of Geocoding API:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=<LATITUDE>, <LONGITURE>&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>`

and parse its JSON result. For example for

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=26.218588, 50.587587&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>`

you got something like that:

```
{
   "plus_code" : {
      "compound_code" : "6H9Q+C2 Manama, Bahrain",
      "global_code" : "7HRG6H9Q+C2"
   },
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Bahrain",
               "short_name" : "BH",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "القضيبية",
               "short_name" : "القضيبية",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "المنامة",
               "short_name" : "المنامة",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "محافظة العاصمة",
               "short_name" : "محافظة العاصمة",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Road 596, Build 326 , Flat 12 - Adliya , Bahrain, المنامة، Bahrain",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 26.218734,
               "lng" : 50.587591
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.2200829802915,
                  "lng" : 50.5889399802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 26.21738501970849,
                  "lng" : 50.5862420197085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJf7pq3DevST4RM9wS0YnAkGk",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "6H9Q+F2 Manama, Bahrain",
            "global_code" : "7HRG6H9Q+F2"
         },
         "types" : [ "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Hassan Bin Thabit Avenue",
               "short_name" : "Hassan Bin Thabit Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Qudaibiya",
               "short_name" : "Qudaibiya",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Manama",
               "short_name" : "Manama",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Capital Governorate",
               "short_name" : "Capital Governorate",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bahrain",
               "short_name" : "BH",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Hassan Bin Thabit Ave, Manama, Bahrain",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.218572,
                  "lng" : 50.58771420000001
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 26.2184482,
                  "lng" : 50.5874591
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 26.2185067,
               "lng" : 50.5875887
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.2198590802915,
                  "lng" : 50.5889356302915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 26.2171611197085,
                  "lng" : 50.5862376697085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJyekp3TevST4Rfj8TaosVDpE",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Block 326",
               "short_name" : "Block 326",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Qudaibiya",
               "short_name" : "Qudaibiya",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Manama",
               "short_name" : "Manama",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Capital Governorate",
               "short_name" : "Capital Governorate",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bahrain",
               "short_name" : "BH",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Block 326, Manama, Bahrain",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.2234075,
                  "lng" : 50.5912257
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 26.2153032,
                  "lng" : 50.5850888
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 26.2198723,
               "lng" : 50.5879925
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.2234075,
                  "lng" : 50.5912257
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 26.2153032,
                  "lng" : 50.5850888
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJb9O71TevST4RqB02rRcRh1g",
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Qudaibiya",
               "short_name" : "Qudaibiya",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Manama",
               "short_name" : "Manama",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Capital Governorate",
               "short_name" : "Capital Governorate",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bahrain",
               "short_name" : "BH",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Qudaibiya, Manama, Bahrain",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.2297388,
                  "lng" : 50.59774059999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 26.2077109,
                  "lng" : 50.5822785
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 26.2186782,
               "lng" : 50.5938215
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.2297388,
                  "lng" : 50.59774059999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 26.2077109,
                  "lng" : 50.5822785
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJic3RMUivST4Ru9BNKfSYXcw",
         "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Manama",
               "short_name" : "Manama",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Capital Governorate",
               "short_name" : "Capital Governorate",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bahrain",
               "short_name" : "BH",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Manama, Bahrain",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.262323,
                  "lng" : 50.62693119999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 26.1909103,
                  "lng" : 50.5511212
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 26.2235305,
               "lng" : 50.5875935
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.262323,
                  "lng" : 50.62693119999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 26.1909103,
                  "lng" : 50.5511212
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJLaZ2J3KvST4RwmAPB6Y4Z4s",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Capital Governorate",
               "short_name" : "Capital Governorate",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bahrain",
               "short_name" : "BH",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Capital Governorate, Bahrain",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.262323,
                  "lng" : 50.62693119999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 26.1909103,
                  "lng" : 50.51370679999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 26.2285161,
               "lng" : 50.5860497
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.262323,
                  "lng" : 50.62693119999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 26.1909103,
                  "lng" : 50.51370679999999
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJo5Ng-m-vST4RGbXeFQV4px4",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Bahrain",
               "short_name" : "BH",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Bahrain",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.3469001,
                  "lng" : 50.8509064
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 25.5349999,
                  "lng" : 50.324246
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 26.0667,
               "lng" : 50.5577
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 26.3469001,
                  "lng" : 50.8509064
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 25.5349999,
                  "lng" : 50.324246
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJEaJHak5SSD4RRhDa2-JQlC4",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

where you can find block name e.g. at `"formatted_address"` tag:

`"formatted_address" : "Block 326, Manama, Bahrain",`

So, you just need to carefully parse JSON response.

Comment: man, must i get my Gmail acc to be paid to use the Geocoding?

Comment: @MoustafEL-Saghier if you within 200$ monthly credit - no. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/).

Comment: sir, please is that can be done on OSM? 
OSM => Open Street Map.

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier Please create separate question.

Comment: Do any hints about make response in a specific language?

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier You can use optional `language` parameter in you request URL, e.g. `language=uk` for Ukrainian: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=uk&latlng=26.218588, 50.587587&key=<YOUR_KEY>`, but it translate only that it can translate (e.g. if corresponding names in target language exists in the Google database). List of supported languages you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport).

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier Also you can use some workaround: parse response in original language, than translate each part of address components to target with [translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs), but that might be a bad idea, because for geographic names the translation might not match very well.

Comment: ya, i know that but my issue with this case https://prnt.sc/tp918b client don't wanna both being there or mixed up two languages, if I translated into hendi, for example, I get this https://prnt.sc/tp91zd and not accepted

Comment: @MoustafaEL-Saghier Split it to parts and use [detecting-language](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/detecting-language) for each part, then translate each part to target language. Or just hide parts in "non target" language.  Seems there is no other way to do that.