# Extract block number from address located in Bahrain Country

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I want to get the block number of an address located in Bahrain.

First of all, let me show you what block numbers are.
Bahrain is divided into areas and each area has a block number like in the photo below:

[image]

So, I hope the block number becomes clear to you now.

I've implemented a basic app to get the location and some of its info like this:

[image]

This address is located in `BLOCK 326` but I don't have any idea about how to get the correct block number.

This feature is already built in to the `Uber` and `trycarriage` apps.

I'm using the OSM API to get my data.

Any good ideas about how this can be done?

I know how to do that in Google maps but how do I achieve this in OSM?
Are these values available on the OSM map?

Comment: down vote : question asked twice in 4 months .. and there is already good answer on the first question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349438/extract-block-number-from-address-located-in-bahrain

Comment: if you can focus or cost urself time to read the post you will find that it different from google maps to OSM but you didn't :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the Block numbers on the OSM maps, but I couldn't find anything (no matter at what zoom level).

Therefore I would suppose that the API also can't help with this.
Maybe you should try another Map API for this one.

[image]

Comment: it's shown on the google map, but, to get it must enable payment method. so, I was asking if that applied or not in the OSM

Comment: Yeah, I found it on the Google Maps map too, but, as already said, I don't think it works with OSM.

Comment: you mean we can't get block number using OSM?

Comment: Why would they include them in the API if you can't find them anywhere on the map? I don't think you can...

Comment: ok, thanks, do you recommend any other free map API that has the block number for android?

Comment: No, sorry. I have never used one, but I think it's hard to find any other good map API that is free to use. Most of the the map providers want to have money for this...

Comment: i did some search and here are the results: i picked random road (way element) from OSM and queried nominatim: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/lookup?osm_ids=W478334323 .. the post code is the block number

Comment: i dont know if u get blocked by doing this as its not api .. but try this get request: https://www.openstreetmap.org/geocoder/search_osm_nominatim_reverse?lat=26.22623&lon=50.54052&zoom=19&minlon=50.539416074752815&minlat=26.225099004762875&maxlon=50.54167181253434&maxlat=26.2272235853456